# How to convert date to y-m-d

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to convert the following date to Y-m-d but it does not work correctly

```
$date='Thu Jul 01 2021 15:22:00 GMT 0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)';
$from=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

`echo $from;` displays `1970-01-01`

Comment: PHP/`strtotime` doesn't understand your format; more precisely the time zone information. First, it should be GMT+0300. Second, strotime doesn't know "Eastern European Summer Time", it only knows _EEST_. Third, redundant information. GMT+0300 is the same as EEST. Fourth, the parenthesis also throw off the parser.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$date='Thu Jul 01 2021 15:22:00 GMT +3:00';
echo $from=date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($date));

Comment: @maryisdead that is the format i recieve it from $_GET

Comment: @chris227 Can't help you with that. It remains invalid. :P If you know that it's coming in like that, you can easily fix it? Also, have a look at [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).